# Bootsfaces modalbox filled with wrong user data from a dataTable column when click edit button

Tags: jsf, datatable, modal-dialog, bootsfaces

**This is my Table**

> Lets say i have 10 user in the table and i click user id 2 to edit, the bootsfaces modal display the last user in the table into modal; which is user id 10.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="add9">
<h:form class="form-horizontal" >
  <h3 class="title-section title-bar-high mb-40">System User Report</h3>
      <div class="orders-info">
         <div class="table-responsive">
             <b:dataTable class="table table-bordered table-responsive" var="user" value="#{userBean.findsAll()}" onorder="console.log('order');" onselect="ajax:userBean.editUser(user)" onpage="console.log('page');" >
                  <h:column>
                      <f:facet name="header">Sr. No.</f:facet>
                       <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
                  </h:column>
                  <h:column>
                     <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                     <h:outputText value="#{user.userName}" />
                  </h:column>
                  <h:column>
                     <f:facet name="header">Status</f:facet>
                     <h:outputText value="#{user.userLevel}" />
                  </h:column>
                  <h:column>
                     <f:facet name="header">Mobile</f:facet>
                     <h:outputText value="#{user.userPhone}" />
                   </h:column>
                   <h:column>
                     <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
                     <h:outputText value="#{user.userEmail}" />
                   </h:column>
                   <h:column>
                      <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
                      <h:outputText value="#{user.userDate}" />
                   </h:column>
                   <h:column>
                       <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
                      <b:commandButton iconAwesome="pencil" look="link" action="#{userBean.editUser(user)}" onclick="$('.modalPseudoClass').modal();return false;">
                            <f:ajax execute="#{userBean.editUser(user)}" render="@none" />
                        </b:commandButton>
                        <b:commandButton action="#{userBean.deleteUser(user)}" onclick="return confirm('You Are About You Delete This User!')" iconAwesome="trash" look="link">                            
                        </b:commandButton>
                  </h:column>
             </b:dataTable>
           </div>
         </div>
      </h:form>
    </div>
```

**This is my beans controller**

```
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private UserFacade userFacade;

    private User user;

    public UserBean() {
        user = new User();
    }

    public UserFacade getUserFacade() {
        return userFacade;
    }

    public void setUserFacade(UserFacade userFacade) {
        this.userFacade = userFacade;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void deleteUser(User user){
        userFacade.remove(user);
    }

    public void editUser(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void editUser(){
        userFacade.edit(this.getUser());
        user = new User();
    }   
}
```

**This is my bootsfaces modal**

```
<f:view>
                <h:form class="form-horizontal">
                    <b:modal id="amodal" title="Basic info and Contact No. #{userBean.user.id}" styleClass="modalPseudoClass">
                        <div class="profile-details tab-content">
                            <div class="personal-info">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:outputLabel class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="userName">User Name:</h:outputLabel>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <h:inputText class="form-control" id="userName" value="#{userBean.user.userName}" title="UserName" requiredMessage="" />
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:outputLabel class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstName">First Name:</h:outputLabel>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <h:inputText class="form-control" id="firstName" value="#{userBean.user.firstName}" title="FirstName" requiredMessage="" />
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:outputLabel class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="lastName">last-name:</h:outputLabel>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <h:inputText class="form-control" id="lastName" value="#{userBean.user.lastName}" title="LastName" requiredMessage="" />
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:outputLabel class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="userEmail">E-mail Address:</h:outputLabel>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <h:inputText class="form-control" id="userEmail" value="#{userBean.user.userEmail}" title="UserEmail" requiredMessage="" />
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:outputLabel class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="userPostal">Zip Code:</h:outputLabel>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <h:inputText class="form-control" id="userPostal" value="#{userBean.user.userPostal}" title="UserPostal" requiredMessage="" />
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:outputLabel class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="userPhone">Phone:</h:outputLabel>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <h:inputText class="form-control" id="userPhone" value="#{userBean.user.userPhone}" title="UserPhone" requiredMessage="" />
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:outputLabel class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="userCountry">Country:</h:outputLabel>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <div class="custom-select">
                                            <h:selectOneMenu id="userCountry" value="#{userBean.user.userCountry}" title="UserCountry" class="select2">
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "o" itemLabel = "Please Select" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "Bangladesh" itemLabel = "Bangladesh" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "Spain" itemLabel = "Spain" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "Belgium" itemLabel = "Belgium" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "Ecuador" itemLabel = "Ecuador" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "Ghana" itemLabel = "Ghana" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "South Africa" itemLabel = "South Africa" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "India" itemLabel = "India" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "Pakistan" itemLabel = "Pakistan" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "Thailand" itemLabel = "Thailand" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "Malaysia" itemLabel = "Malaysia" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "Italy" itemLabel = "Italy" /> 
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue = "Japan" itemLabel = "Japan" /> 
                                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:outputLabel class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="userLevel">User Level:</h:outputLabel>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <div class="custom-select">
                                            <h:selectOneMenu class="select2" id="userLevel" value="#{userBean.user.userLevel}" title="UserLevel">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose item" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.findAllUserRole()}" var="user" itemLabel="#{user.name}" itemValue="#{user.name}" />
                                                <f:ajax render="#{user.name}" />
                                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:outputLabel class="col-sm-3 control-label" value="Town / City:" for="userTown" />
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <h:inputText class="form-control" id="userTown" value="#{userBean.user.userTown}" title="UserTown" requiredMessage="" />
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:outputLabel class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="userAbout">About Me:</h:outputLabel>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <h:inputTextarea class="form-control" id="userAbout" value="#{userBean.user.userAbout}" title="UserAbout" requiredMessage="" style="height: 150px;" rows="8" />
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <div class="form-group mb-none">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <b:commandButton value="Save" look="success" style="width:80px" action="#{userBean.editUser()}" a:dismiss="modal" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <b:button value="Close" look="warning"  style="width:80px" dismiss="modal" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </f:facet>
                        </div>
                    </b:modal>
                </h:form>
            </f:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the content of the modal when the user selects a row. You know, the datatable and the modal are part of the same XHTML file, so they are rendered at the same time. Of course, that's too early, so the modal shows the wrong user if it isn't updated.

BTW, I believe it's a good idea to rename `user` to `selectedUser`, initialize it with null, and to render the content of the modal only if the `selectedUser` is not null. That way, you notice when something's wrong. Plus, less HTML code is sent to the client.

Not directly related to your question: your code snippet calls `editUser()` multiple times. You may want to do some housekeeping.